# Azure DevOps PublishPipelineArtifact not running on failure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want it to run on success or failure. I am generating my own extent report that gets sent to a .zip file. I am trying to publish this, no matter if the tests pass or fail. I have the template set up with the following, but it says it is skipped. How can I get this to run on pass or fail?:

```
# .NET Desktop
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1   
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: '*.zip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The `continueOnError: true` will not fail the pipeline if uploading artifacts fails. `condition: succeededOrFailed()` will run the task even if a previous task has failed.

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions

Comment: i think it will run it even if you cancelled the build, whereas `failed()` will do what you describe

Comment: It's `succeededOrFailed()` to not run when the job is cancelled.